# aggregate and groupby data then sort according to a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions, data-analysis

in a dataset like below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'AuthorName':["Wendelaar Bonga"," Sjoerd E.", "Grätzel"," Michael", "Willett", "Walter C.",
                             "Kessler", "Ronald C.", "Witten, Edward", "Wang, Zhong Lin"],
                 'seniorityLevel':[10, 45, 13, 89, 3, 8, 19, 22, 10, 59],
               'SubjectField': ["Biomedical Engineering", "Inorganic & Nuclear Chemistry",
                                "Organic Chemistry", "Biomedical Engineering", "Developmental Biology",
                                "Mechanical Engineering & Transports", "Biomedical Engineering", "Microbiology",
                                "Cardiovascular System & Hematology", "Biomedical Engineering"],
              'NumberOfPapers':[109, 284, 34, 109, 78, 90, 109, 54, 32, 109],
              })
```

I need to calculate minimum, mean, median, and maximum for seniority_level and number of papers for each subject field. Display top-10 and bottom-10 tables when data is sorted by mean seniority level.
I tried this code:

```
d=data.groupby(["SubjectField"]).agg({'seniorityLevel':['min', 'mean', 'median', 'max'],'NumberOfPapers':['min', 'mean', 'median', 'max']})
```

but I cant sort the table by seniority level

Answer (score 3):

Try using a tuple to sort multiIndex header columns.

```
d_sort = d.sort_values(('seniorityLevel', 'mean'))

pd.concat([d_sort.head(2), d_sort.tail(2)])
```

Output (here just showing top 2 and bottom 2):

```
                                    seniorityLevel                   NumberOfPapers                 
                                               min   mean median max            min mean median  max
SubjectField                                                                                        
Developmental Biology                            3   3.00      3   3             78   78     78   78
Mechanical Engineering & Transports              8   8.00      8   8             90   90     90   90
Biomedical Engineering                          10  44.25     39  89            109  109    109  109
Inorganic & Nuclear Chemistry                   45  45.00     45  45            284  284    284  284
```